# How to configure GraphQL extension for VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, graphql

I'm trying to configure VSCode [GraphQL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GraphQL.vscode-graphql) extension, but its info is some obscure for me.

I have this basic Flutter project structure:

```
.
├── analysis_options.yaml
├── android
├── assets
├── lib
│   ├── graphql
│   │   └── *.gql
│   ├── main.dart
│   ├── private
│   │   └── graphql.config.json
│   └── shared
├── pubspec.lock
├── pubspec.yaml
├── README.md
├── test
└── tutorial_with_hasura_server.iml
```

I've created `graphql.config.json` into `./lib/private` directory with this setting:

```json
{
  "schema": {
    "request": {
      "url": "https://hasura.io/learn/graphql",
      "method": "POST",
      "postIntrospectionQuery": true,
      "options": {
        "headers": {
          "Authorization": "Bearer 1234567890123456789"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Meanwhile in VSCode `settings.json` I've added this line:

```json
"graphql-config.load.filePath": "./lib/private/graphql.config.json",
```

I'm trying to run a simple GraphQL query operation which is stored in a file with extension GQL located in `./lib/graphql` directory, but no result, no error message, nothing at all. What am I missing?

Comment: I think your `graphql.config.json` is simply wrong. If you want to pass a header you can do it like this: https://graphql-config.com/schema#passing-headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing the following in a `graphql.config.json` file at your project root. The name of the project should be the path to the directory that contains your graphql folder. For OP, that would be `lib`:

```
{
    "projects": {
        "lib": {
            "extensions": {
                "endpoints": {
                    "default": {
                        "url": "https://hasura.io/learn/graphql",
                        "headers": {
                            "Authorization": "Bearer 1234567890123456789"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The second way is working for me, but `graphql.config.json` needs to be located in project root and no need for modifying `settings.json`

Comment: Thanks, I edited the solution to clarify that.